# google maps works only on wifi?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an android app in which I have used google maps. these maps are loading only in wifi connection and not in any other internet connection.

Can anyone tell me Why is this happening?

Comment: Interesting, I thought in android google maps are not depends on type of internet (Wifi/LAN...) :-)

Comment: may be because of slow internet connection the Map is taking time for loading.

Comment: the only one problem may be the speed of internet connection. please check for it.

Comment: Without some errors/exceptions, we can guess all day long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WIFI is not must for Google Map. Google Map used the Internet Connection whether you can access it from SIM Card GPRS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a firewall is blocking 2g/3g network connections. Try disabling the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Having had the same problem, check if the Data Connection of your device is ON.